# constructing image after applying inverse fourier transform opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, fft, mat, ifft

I am trying to apply fourier transform to an image, by following the code from link http://www.docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/core/discrete_fourier_transform/discrete_fourier_transform.html , after this I am trying to remove the noise components which are visible in fourier spectrum as horizontal and vertical lines, like in this image shown in link below: (http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/fourier/twigs_spectrum.png) - Spectrum image

Now after zeroing out the noise pixel locations in the spectrum, I just want to see how the original image is changed now.
I have applied inverse DFT to it, and reconstructed the image also but the image is null image.  Here is my code:

```
Mat magI_copy;
magI.copyTo(magI_copy);
//magI.convertTo(magI_copy, CV_8U);
//imshow("image", magI_copy); waitKey();
for (int i = 0; i < 86; i++){
    for (int j = 127; j < 130;j++){
        magI_copy.at<float>(i, j) = 0;
    }
}
for (int i = 171; i < magI_copy.rows; i++){
    for (int j = 127; j < 130; j++){
        magI_copy.at<float>(i, j) = 0;
    }
}
for (int i = 126; i < 131; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 87; j++){
        magI_copy.at<float>(i, j) = 0;
    }
}
for (int i = 126; i < 131; i++){
    for (int j = 170; j < magI_copy.cols; j++){
        magI_copy.at<float>(i, j) = 0;
    }
}
///////////Inverse Transform

cv::Mat inverseTransform;
cv::dft(magI_copy, inverseTransform, cv::DFT_INVERSE | cv::DFT_REAL_OUTPUT);
normalize(inverseTransform, inverseTransform, 0, 1, CV_MINMAX);
Mat finalimage;
inverseTransform.convertTo(finalimage, CV_8U);
```

Comment: @Miki my question is after applying IDFT, how can I reconstruct the image

Comment: Since you're normalizing the data between 0 and 1, I suppose you need to  scale them to 0,255: `inverseTransform.convertTo(finalimage, CV_8U, 255); ` Note that in the linked answer there's no normalization, though.

Answer (score -1):

[Inverse DFT](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#void%20idft(InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20int%20flags,%20int%20nonzeroRows)) is what you need here. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761526/how-to-do-inverse-dft-in-opencv) is the answer for your question.

Comment: Next time you find that the correct answer to the question is somewhere else on SO, please mark as duplicate instead of writing an answer with a link

Comment: @Miki ok, thanks for the tip.